# Rails STI validation inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, sti

I have STI models in my Rails application. The ancestor model has validations with the `validates_...` methods which are working fine.

But I have custom validations as well, and I would like to add more different custom validations in the descendants. These custom validations would depend on the class.

If I write

```
class DescendantA < Ancestor

  protected
    def validate
      # ...
    end
end
```

It simply overwrites the original validations, so I loose the original inherited validations.

Is there a convention to do this in Rails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would it not be sufficient to add `super` at the end of the `validate` method in the child, so that the parent's `validate` method would also be called?